# Format numericInput in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to format the numeric input in an R shiny app just for display purpose. When I do that on load it shows the number and then the numericInput box goes blank.

```
library(shiny)

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
        numericInput("inp1", label = ("Total"), value = 11000000)
      )
    ),

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      observe({
        updateNumericInput(session, "inp1", label = ("Total"),
                          paste("S", value = prettyNum(input$inp1, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)))
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible without some loss of functionality. See [this link](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/barbara/format-numbers/)

Comment: This need a js script right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a number in `updateNumericInput` and `paste("S", value = prettyNum(input$inp1, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE))` is a character as would be the value of `prettyNum()`

Comment: Could you give an example. I am not sure I understand what is change you want me to make

Comment: I wanted to point that you would need to use textInput instead of numericInput as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791983/how-to-format-r-shiny-numericinput